# ZINGCHART JSON FORMATTING - Parsing JSON I GET through a HTTP request from my REST API when using ZingChart

Tags: json, rest, zingchart

When I get data from my REST API, my JSON response is the following:

[{"_id":"5686ec582df17bea255ec3c2","litres":3,"minute":54,"__v":0},             {"_id":"5686f4b22df17bea255ec3c3","litres":4,"minute":55,"__v":0},{"_id":"568bda9531906b7020d48664","litres":5,"minute":56,"__v":0},{"_id":"568be3dc31906b7020d48665","litres":12,"minute":57,"__v":0}]

I want to have a line chart with litres on the y axis and minutes on the x axis.

How can I parse my JSON so that it is in the correct format for ZingChart for such a graph?

Comment: Which language are you using? Almost all popular languages had some available lib to parse JSON already.

Comment: JavaScript, but my question also asks about how to format my JSON for the format that ZingChart needs, any useful libraries to parse JSON would be much appreciated though, I'm using Angulars $http to get the JSON from my REST API

Answer (score 3):

ZingChart's [docs on line charts](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/line/#line__series_data) show you the various ways to format your data. I'd suggest starting there.

Comment: Do you have any resources for the JSON format required by ZingCharts? Is there a page that specifies the required JSON input?

Comment: The page I sent you has exactly that information. Please read the docs more thoroughly. We're happy to help but the information we provide is just going to be a reiteration of the information on the ZingChart Docs.